# Pdfkit doesn't work locally

Tags: ruby, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-5, pdfkit

I'm using pdfkit to generate pdf, with Rails 5.
When I try to download external website's pages, like google it works. But when I want to download a page of my website it does nothing. The loading cursor load for ever.

Here is my code :

**controller/products**

```
def download
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   file_content = html_to_pdf(request.url, @product.id)
   open_file = File.read(file_content)
   send_data(open_file,
                filename: "ptf_#{@product.id}",
                disposition: 'attachment')
  end
```

**products/show**

```
  <%= button_to 'download', download_product_path(product_id: @product.id), method: :get} %>
```

**Method in a concern**

```
 def html_to_pdf(url, id)
   kit = PDFKit.new(url)
   file = kit.to_file('ptf_'+ id.to_s + '.pdf')
 end
```

If I try with `file_content = html_to_pdf('http://google.com', @product.id)` it works fine. The issue is locally.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Within `download`, what is the value of `request.url`?

Comment: The value is "http://localhost:3000/fr/products/download/2"

Comment: And that request is again handled by `ProductsController#download`, isn't it? You are calling the `download` action recursively. You probably want to generate a PDF from `"http://localhost:3000/fr/products/2"`.

Comment: Yes you're write. So what should I do to avoid this recursion ?

Answer (score 0):

```
file_content = html_to_pdf(request.url, @product.id)
```

`request.url` refers to your current URL, so you are calling the `download` action recursively over and over again.

Instead, you have to use the product's show URL:

```
file_content = html_to_pdf(products_url(@product.id), @product.id)
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers

Comment: Ok so it download a page but a page with an error. I don't know why the url is not properly read. when I use your code the url downloaded is http://localhost:3000/fr/2/products, instead of http://localhost:3000/fr/products/2. If I delete the 's' so => product_url the page load for ever as before.

Comment: @Orsay seems like your routes are configured in a non-standard way. Try `products_url(product_id: @product.id)` (or maybe without `s`). You can check the URL in the rails console via `app.products_url(product_id: 123)` – it has to return `<host>/fr/products/2` in order to work (`<host>` is probably `www.example.com` instead of `localhost`, that's okay). Running `rake routes` will show you the routes in your app. That might help to find the correct one and the correct arguments.

Comment: there is my route :  product GET (/:locale)/products/:id(.:format)                                                 products#show {:locale=>/en|fr/}